# Angular & ag-grid: cannot register framework component using frameworkComponents

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

As part of an Angular application, I am developing a table based on ag-grid and I want to render a certain cell as an html link.

As I am building the columnDefs dynamically, I would like to avoid hardcoding the cell renderer component (**ForeignKeyRendererComponent** in the code below) in the column definition.

Unfortunately, I am not able to register the framework components as per the manual: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/#registering-framework-components

When I do so, I am getting this error:

> Error: No component factory found for fkRenderer. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?
>
> at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3256)

The only way this works is by referencing the cell renderer component directly in the column definition, like this: `cellRendererFramework: ForeignKeyRendererComponent`.

---

**My setup & what I have tried:**

Angular v6.1.10

ag-grid v21.0.1

**module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([ForeignKeyRendererComponent]),
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ForeignKeyRendererComponent,
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ForeignKeyRendererComponent
  ],
});
```

**component.html**

```
<ag-grid-angular style="height: 500px;"
                 class="ag-theme-balham"
                 [context]="context"
                 (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
                 [rowData]="rowData"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                 rowSelection="multiple"
                 pagination=true
                 paginationPageSize=10>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

**component.ts**

```
  private gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
      filter: true
    },
    animateRows: true,
    isExternalFilterPresent: this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this),
    doesExternalFilterPass: this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this),
    frameworkComponents: { fkRenderer: ForeignKeyRendererComponent }
  };
...
this.columnDefs.push({
  headerName: translation,
  field: columnNames[index],
  sortable: true,
  filter: customFilter,
  editable: true,
  cellRendererFramework: 'fkRenderer'
});
```

I have also tried to specify the frameworkComponents independently of the gridOptions: `this.frameworkComponents = { fkRenderer: ForeignKeyRendererComponent }`, but got the same error.

---

**EDIT: Tried Sean Landsman's suggestion:**

Same frameworkComponents definition:

```
frameworkComponents = { fkRenderer: ForeignKeyRendererComponent };
```

But with column definition like this:

```
...
cellRenderer: 'fkRenderer'
...
```

In this case, I am getting a new error:

> custom-error-handler.ts:14 TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'componentFromFramework' of null
>       at UserComponentFactory.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/components/framework/userComponentFactory.js.UserComponentFactory.lookupComponentClassDef
>   (userComponentFactory.js:283)
>       at CellComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/rendering/cellComp.js.CellComp.chooseCellRenderer
>   (cellComp.js:632)
>       at new CellComp (cellComp.js:80)
>       at RowComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.createNewCell
>   (rowComp.js:610)
>       at rowComp.js:594
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at RowComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.insertCellsIntoContainer
>   (rowComp.js:587)
>       at RowComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.refreshCellsInAnimationFrame
>   (rowComp.js:503)
>       at AnimationFrameService.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/misc/animationFrameService.js.AnimationFrameService.executeFrame
>   (animationFrameService.js:84)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)

Comment: did you `import { ForeignKeyRendererComponent } from '...';` at the top of module.ts?

Comment: @DavidP.Hochman Yep -- wouldn't build otherwise ;-)

Comment: I've not seen this error before - if you have a repo (ie plunker or similar) of the problem I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: @SeanLandsman Thanks for the feedback! I'll try to build a toy project that reproduces this, as right now this occurs in our proprietary code.

Comment: @SeanLandsman Update: I made a toy project, using your suggestion, and it works. So I think there must be some other factors in my big project that influence this. Your suggestion was the correct one for this problem, however -- thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it fixed it! :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to register components - by name or by direct reference:

- By name:

```
gridOptions or bind to ag-grid-angular directly:
frameworkComponents: {
    countryCellRenderer: CountryCellRenderer
}

columnDefs: [{
   field: 'country',
   cellRenderer: 'countryCellRenderer'
}]
```

- By reference:

```
columnDefs: [{
   field: 'country',
   cellRendererFramework: CountryCellRenderer
}]
```

In your case I think you're mixing the two - try changing:

`cellRendererFramework: 'fkRenderer'`

to 
`cellRenderer: 'fkRenderer'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry for the delayed response, had to jump to a different project at work. I have tried your suggestion, now I am getting a new error: "Cannot read property 'componentFromFramework' of null". I have updated my post at the bottom with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case someone (teammate) has used Enterprise filter `agSetColumnFilter` in columnDefs, I have just changed it to common `agTextColumnFilter` filter, error disappear

```
columnDefs = [{ 
        headerName: 'Client',
        field: 'client',
        filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
        // agSetColumnFilter - Enterprise feature
    }];
```